# Magento: Display Product Options in Product Page as List Elements in Two Columns

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.9, configurable-product

Having actual Magento 1.9.3 situation...

In product-page there are a lot of configuration options. Need to save space, so need to turn the one column vertical product options list into a two column list to reduce the space to 50%.

Already tried several methods, also this one:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70857/display-product-options-change-layout-of-in-block-after-info-column

in combination with
[Css Styling list elements in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654651/css-styling-list-elements-in-two-columns)

and this
https://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/

But did not figure it out really. Was stopping on the results, to display all in only one horizontal line. The issue is, that if there are 10 attributes to select, the line is becoming very pressed and nothing is recognisable.

**Is anyone out there, who is able to adjust the code?**

Here is the code having in:

/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

```
    <?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
$_jsonConfig = $this->getJsonConfig();
$_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
<div class="items">    
    <dl>
    <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <?php
        $_rendered = false;
        foreach ($_renderers as $_rendererName):
            $_renderer = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getChild($_rendererName);
            if (method_exists($_renderer, 'shouldRender') && $_renderer->shouldRender($_attribute, $_jsonConfig)):
                $_renderer->setProduct($_product);
                $_renderer->setAttributeObj($_attribute);
                echo $_renderer->toHtml();
                $_rendered = true;
                break;
            endif;
        endforeach;

        if (!$_rendered):
        ?>
        <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
        <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
            <div class="input-box">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                  </select>
              </div>
        </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
</div>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $_jsonConfig ?>);
    </script>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after') ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Seeing the output its hard to know what you want exactly, but if you want the options to be in 2 columns this should work.

```css
.items dl {
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.items dl .options-wrapper{
 width: 50%;
}

//If you want on smaller screens to make them 1 row.

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.items dl .options-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
   <?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
$_jsonConfig = $this->getJsonConfig();
$_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
<div class="items">    
    <dl>
    <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <?php
        $_rendered = false;
        foreach ($_renderers as $_rendererName):
            $_renderer = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getChild($_rendererName);
            if (method_exists($_renderer, 'shouldRender') && $_renderer->shouldRender($_attribute, $_jsonConfig)):
                $_renderer->setProduct($_product);
                $_renderer->setAttributeObj($_attribute);
                echo $_renderer->toHtml();
                $_rendered = true;
                break;
            endif;
        endforeach;

        if (!$_rendered):
        ?>
        <div class="options-wrapper">
                <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
        <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
            <div class="input-box">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                  </select>
              </div>
        </dd>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
</div>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $_jsonConfig ?>);
    </script>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after') ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Dear @vasilis-neris! Thanks for the fast response. Yeah, it seems to be the needed. Let me show you the before and after and the customization, which was done now. Here is the CSS > https://jsfiddle.net/yqn9degz/ And here is the before: https://ibb.co/eUnzGV and here after: https://ibb.co/cr9Aqq. But what noticed, is that the Attributes will not be all same of course in the length. So will need to adjust regarding the @media. Maybe you have any other comments regarding the modification?

Comment: The ibb.co links show a blank page. Can you try new ones?